# AEM DEMO MACHINE: Sites > Download Demo Add-on, aem-demomachine-sites empty and sites addon gives error

Tags: ant, aem

https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-demo-machine

Hi,

I just got the AEM Demo Machine up and running, created a demo instance and it works on port 4502&4503.

Add-ons > Assets Demo Addon was installed but Sites gives same error .

When I try to download the AEM Sites Demo Add on under Add-ons > Sites > Download Demo Add-on.

I get this error:

> Running ANT target: download_sites Downloading Latest AEM Sites Demo
>   Add-on in /dist/downloads Download in progress, please wait until
>   build is successful Extracting Latest AEM Sites Demo Add-on in
>   /dist/sites Sorry, this target couldn't be completed properly The
>   error message is: Error while expanding
>   C:\Users\farhan.mohammed\aem-demo-machine\dist\downloads\aem-demomachine-sites.zip
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure you are running the most recent version of the AEM Demo Machine (git pull the changes). I just tried and the download worked just fine.

Tested on Feb 1st, 2016 at 5:40PM CET.

Running ANT target: download_sites
      Downloading Latest AEM Sites Demo Add-on in /dist/downloads
      Download in progress, please wait until build is successful
      aem-demomachine-sites.zip (8.4 MB)
      aem-demomachine-sites.zip (25.8 MB)
      Extracting Latest AEM Sites Demo Add-on in /dist/sites

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 24 seconds